# Gradient of a norm with power

Tags: vector-analysis

Can someone suggest me the approach to find the gradient of 4-norm ?  eg:(||x||) where it is not a one norm but 4 norm to the power of 4.

[image]

I need to solve this question for my practice for the exams. Any input would be helpful. We will consider 4th root for the norm here.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax and see [MathJax tutorial](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189). Please [don't use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to those who use screen readers. Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) for information on writing a good question. People will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include an explanation of your own attempts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The norm itself must have a 4th root. But in the picture, the function $f$ has a power 4. So we can look at the function simply as $f(x) = x_1^4 + x_2^4 + ... +x_d^4$, where $x_i$s are the components of $x$. Therefore the gradient is simply $$\nabla f = 4 (x_1^3, x_2^3, ..., x_d^3 ) \in \mathbb{R}^d$$

Comment: What does "if the 2[nd] root is meant" mean?  If $\lVert x\rVert_4$ is defined using a square root instead of a 4th root?

Comment: I guess no-one can stop you from putting $\lVert x\rVert_4 = \sqrt{\sum_i x_i^4}$, but it's not a norm.  For example, with that definition, $\lVert1 + 1\rVert_4 = 4 > 2 = \lVert1\rVert_4 + \lVert1\rVert_4$.

Comment: Ok then. You should consider the 4th root only.